# wtforms field created through setattr() loses properties

Tags: python, class, wtforms, setattr

I am trying to create a form in python / Flask that will add some dynamic slider inputs to a set of standard fields. I am struggling to get it to work properly, though.

Most of the web forms in my app are static, created through wtforms as in:

```
    class CritiqueForm(Form):

        rating = IntegerField('Rating')
        comment = TextAreaField('Comments')
        submit = SubmitField('Save Critique')
```

When I am explicit like that, I can get the expected results by using the `CritiqueForm()` in the view and passing the form object to render in the template.

However, I have a critique form that needs to dynamically include some sliders for rating criteria specific to a particular record. The number of sliders can vary form one record to the next, as will the text and IDs that come from the record's associated criteria.

When I looked for some ways to handle this, I found a possible solution from dezza ([Dynamic forms from variable length elements: wtforms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12353603/dynamic-forms-from-variable-length-elements-wtforms)) by creating a class method in the form, which I could then call before instantiating the form I want to render. As in:

```
    class CritiqueForm(Form):

        rating = IntegerField('Rating')
        comment = TextAreaField('Comments')
        submit = SubmitField('Save Critique')

        @classmethod
        def append_slider(cls, name, label):
            setattr(cls, name, IntegerField(label))
            return cls
```

where 'append_slider' is always an `IntegerField` with a label I provide. This works enough to allow me to populate the criteria sliders in the view, as in:

```
    @app.route('/critique/<url_id>/edit', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
    def edit_critique(url_id):
        from app.models import RecordModel
        from app.models.forms import CritiqueForm

        record = RecordModel.get_object_by_url_id(url_id)
        if not record: abort(404)

        # build editing form
        ratings = list()
        for i, criterium in enumerate(record.criteria):
            CritiqueForm.append_slider('rating_' + str(i+1),criterium.name)
            ratings.append('form.rating_' + str(i+1))
        form = CritiqueForm(request.form)

        # Process valid POST
        if request.method=='POST' and form.validate():
           # Process the submitted form and show updated read-only record        
            return render_template('critique.html')

        # Display edit form
        return render_template('edit_critique.html',
            form=form,
            ratings=ratings,
            )
```

The `ratings` list is built to give the template an easy way to reference the dynamic fields:

```
    {% for rating_field in ratings %}
        {{ render_slider_field(rating_field, label_visible=True, default_value=0) }} 
    {% endfor %}
```

where `render_slider_field` is a macro to turn the IntegerField into a slider.

With `form.rating`—an integer field explicitly defined in `CritiqueForm`—there is no problem and the slider is generated with a label, as expected. With the dynamic integer fields, however, I cannot reference the `label` value in the integer field. The last part of the stack trace looks like:

```
    File "/home/vagrant/msp/app/templates/edit_critique.html", line 41, in block "content"
    {{ render_slider_field(rating_field, label_visible=True, default_value=0) }}

    File "/home/vagrant/msp/app/templates/common/form_macros.html", line 49, in template
    {% set label = kwargs.pop('label', field.label.text) %}

    File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/msp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 397, in getattr
    return getattr(obj, attribute)

    UndefinedError: 'str object' has no attribute 'label'
```

Through some debugging, I have confirmed that none of the expected field properties (e.g., name, short_name, id ...) are showing up. When the dust settles, I just want this:

```
        CritiqueForm.append_slider('rating', 'Rating')
```

to be equivalent to this:

```
        rating = IntegerField('Rating')
```

Is the setattr() technique inherently limiting in what information can be included in the form, or am I just initializing or referencing the field properties incorrectly?

EDIT:
Two changes allowed my immediate blockers to be removed.

1) I was improperly referencing the form field in the template. The field parameters (e.g., label) appeared where expected with this change:

```
    {% for rating_field in ratings %}
            {{ render_slider_field(form[rating_field], label_visible=True, default_value=0) }} 
    {% endfor %}
```

where I replace the string `rating_field` with `form[rating_field]`.

2) To address the problem of dynamically changing a base class from the view, a new form class `ThisForm()` is created to extend my base `CritiqueForm`, and then the dynamic appending is done there:

```
    class ThisForm(CritiqueForm):
        pass

    # build criteria form fields
    ratings = list()
    for i, criterium in enumerate(record.criteria):
        setattr(ThisForm, 'rating_' + str(i+1), IntegerField(criterium.name))
        ratings.append('rating_' + str(i+1))

    form = ThisForm(request.form)
```

I don't know if this addresses the anticipated performance and data integrity problems noted in the comments, but it at least seems a step in the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

`setattr(obj, name, value)` is the very exact equivalent of `obj.name = value` - both being syntactic sugar for `obj.__setattr__(name, value)` -, so your problem is not with "some limitation" of `setattr()` but first with how `wtform.Form` works. If you look at the [source code](https://github.com/wtforms/wtforms/blob/master/wtforms/form.py), you can see there's much more to make fields and form work together than just having the fields declared as class attributes (metaclass magic involved...). IOW, you'll have to go thru the source code to find out how to dynamically add fields to a form.

Also, your code tries to set the new fields on the class itself. **This is a big NO NO** in a multiprocess / multithreaded / long-running process environnement with concurrent access - each request will modify the (shared at process level) form class, adding or overriding fields aphazardly. It might seem to work on a single-process single-threaded dev server with a single concurrent user but will break in production with the most unpredictable errors or (worse) wrong results.

So what you want to find out is really how to dynamically add fields to a form *instance* - or, as an alternative, how to dynamically build a new temporary form class (which is far from difficult really - remember that Python classes are objects too).

Comment: Thanks. I made an adjustment to the `edit_critique` view to avoid making changes to the main CritiqueForm(), instead using it as a base for a form class created and altered within the view. I don't know if that addresses the NO-NO concern you mention, but it turned out not to be my blocking issue.

I was referencing the name, not the form field, when trying to render the slider. I changed **rating_field** to **form[rating_field]**, and that gave me my field parameters.

Comment: `setattr` doesn't work with instance of wtforms either

Comment: @TomSawyer if the point is to dynamically add fields to the form then it indeed won't work that way for the very same reasons mentionned in my answer - there's more to adding a field than setting it as attribute -, and it still have nothing to do with `setattr()` itself.